# Javascript Scope and Closure, variable keeps its value

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm having trouble using a class method, basically it is a function scope problem (I guess).

The JS code is:

```
MysqlClass.prototype.registrar = function(usuario,password,correo,socket){
    var resultado;
    this.connection.query("SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?;",[usuario],function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err){
            resultado = true;
        }
        if(rows.length==1){
            resultado = true;
        }else{
            resultado = false;
        }
    });
    console.log(resultado);
}
```

`console.log(resultado)` shows `undefined` when I want to show `true` or `false`

I'm using `NodeJS` with `node-mysql`

Comment: you have to see what the result is in that callback.

Comment: Because the callback is executed asynchronously. Put that log inside the callback and it'll work

Comment: I'm also pretty sure you wanna change your logic there. If `rows.length != 1`, `resultado` will be set to `false`, even if `err` was set. Just feels like that's not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`query()` is an asynchronous operation. That means if you want to do something after querying the database, you must place the relevant code **within** the callback. Your code would look like:

```
MysqlClass.prototype.registrar = function(usuario,password,correo,socket){
    var resultado;
    this.connection.query("SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?;",[usuario],function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err){
            resultado = true;
        }
        if(rows.length==1){
            resultado = true;
        }else{
            resultado = false;
        }
        console.log(resultado);
    });
}
```

---

You may want to rewrite `registrar()` so it will call a callback function after querying the database:

```
MysqlClass.prototype.registrar = function(usuario, password, correo, socket, cb) {
    var resultado;
    this.connection.query("SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?;",[usuario],function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err){
            resultado = true;
        }
        if(rows.length==1){
            resultado = true;
        }else{
            resultado = false;
        }
        cb && cb(resultado);
    });
}
```

and use it like:

```
var MysqlClassInstance = new MysqlClass();
// ...
MysqlClassInstance.registrar(usuario, password, correo, socket, function (resultado) {
    console.log(resultado);
});
```